# How to use " 's " correctly?

Tags: possessives

Could you tell me if the phrase

> The rice's price sharply raised in Brazil

is correct? I have a doubt regarding the `'s`. Can I use it as I wrote above?

Comment: _The rice's price_ is grammatically correct, but in a context like this we would normally prefer _the price of rice_. Also, it's _rose sharply_.

Answer (score 2):

When referring to costs in a general way, it's more natural to say `the price of X`. For countable nouns like house, you use the plural. For uncountable nouns like rice, you just use the word.

> The price of rice in Brazil rose sharply this week.

> The price of houses in Britain has fallen in recent times.

On a side note, 'raise' is often confused with 'rise', but they are [two different verbs](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-raise-rise.htm), one being transitive and other intransitive. The base form, simple past, and past participle are:

rise - rose - risen
raise - raised - raised